# Are the following extensions normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

> Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2}), L=K(\sqrt[3]{6+i}), M=K(\sqrt[6]{6+i})$. Which of $K\subset L,K\subset M, L\subset M$ is a normal extension. What is their degree and find a Basis for each.

As far as I understood it for it to be a normal extension it has to be a splitting field of a polynomial in the smaller field. The problem is that I don't know how to check it and the problem arises that I don't know how elements in L and M for example look like.
I would really need some help.

Comment: I would suggest that you solve the "second part" first, namely "What is their degree and find a Basis for each". You may post your progress on that second part.

Comment: I would say that the degree of L would be 3 and of M would be 6 and of K would be 2? In L and M only seeing it form the degree of the square root and therefore of the polynomial that can be created from it and in K following the same logic that we would follow with Q(sqrt{2}). Probably I am completely wrong